# What is the csproj.csdat file for

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-studio-2015

I recently switched to Visual Studio 2015 (Community edition). Since then, from time to time I have the issue, that if I want to undo my changes or drop a feature branch, I got an error message saying:

> The process cannot access the file '...\MyProject.csproj.csdat' because it is being used by another process.

If I close and reopen VS, the operation goes through without a problem. In case it matters, we use `git`.

So my questions are:

- What is the `MyProject.csproj.csdat` file for?
- Should it be part of source control at all?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what it's used for either, but I suspect that you're perfectly fine to simply exclude it from Git.

If it's a file that visual studio is tracking on it's own, then it's very likely just a part of something that VS is doing internally and isn't actually relevant to your projects source code.

Comment: I too think it is fine to exclude, but it is included in our builds (so far). It would be fine if Microsoft could have documented what this file is for...